# Angular 16+ Resolver start before APP_INITIALIZER has end

Tags: angular, resolver, app-initializer

I'm facing strange behavior when using angular V16 and the new **resolveFN**.

If I call the page directly from the browser (entering "localhost:4200/customer/123" for example), the resolver is executed **BEFORE** the APP_INITIALIZER have finished loading and so generate an error in my resolver because everything are not all load.

Any clues on that strange behavior?

Provider :

```
{
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (
            injector: Injector) => {
            return () => {

                const dbService = injector.get(DbService);
                return dbService.initialize();
            };
        },
        deps: [Injector],
        multi: true
    }
```

Resolver :

```
export const CustomerResolver: ResolveFn<ICustomer> =
(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
    customersService = inject(CustomersService),
    errorsService = inject(ErrorsService),
) => {

    let etag: string | null | undefined = "";
    const customer_Id = route.paramMap.get('customer_Id');
    
    if (customer_Id) {

        return customersService.getById(customer_Id)
            .pipe(
                
                takeLast(1),
                catchError(errorsService.catch),                                    
               );
    }

    return EMPTY;
}
```

Edit 1

For example you can test with a DbService like this one :

```
export class DbService {
public initialize(): Observable<boolean> {
console.log(`Start ServiceDb`);
const init = new Subject<boolean>();
setTimeout(() => {
  init.next(true);
  init.complete();
console.log(`End ServiceDb`);
}, 500);
return init;
}
}
```

And a Resolver like this one :

```
export const CustomerResolver: ResolveFn<ICustomer> =
(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
) => {
    const customer_Id = route.paramMap.get('customer_Id');
    console.log('customer resolver');
    return EMPTY;
}
```

You will see in the console :

> Start ServiceDb
>
> customer resolver
>
> End ServiceDb

It's like the resolver didn't wait for the init end

Comment: Please share what kind of error occurs. Is it a NullInjector? Also, what does `dbService.initialize()` return?

Comment: Isn't your `dbService.initialize()` async ? You likely need to await it !

Comment: Pretty sure @MatthieuRiegler is correct. Dadv, if you want to avoir that kind of headache you can also activate this rule: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md

Comment: dbService.initialize() return an Observable that complete when all the initialization is done. I didn't use Promise for this service, but i try with Promise and await (and async) and it's the same behavior. It's like the route is launch just after the APP_Initializer is launch

Comment: My error in the resolver is because all my init function are not load before it is call  -  See my Edit 1 for more informations

Comment: Note that this behavior only appear when you access a route from the browser navigation and not if you use a routerlink. For example if you refresh the browser.